# Why is it not drawing the image, and giving a Type Error?

Tags: javascript, html, web, game-development

I recently started using javascript for a school project. Right now I have a tileset, "grass.png". It is full of 32 by 32 tiles and I would like to eventually create a map editor. To do this I need to have all my tiles stored in a dictionary. When I try to store a bitmap of an image and try to draw it, it results in a type error.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

var tileSize = 32;
var tilex = Math.ceil(canvas.width / tileSize);
var tiley = Math.ceil(canvas.height / tileSize);
var tiles = {};
var images = ['performanceTask Assets/Grass.png', 'performanceTask Assets/Plant.png', 'performanceTask Assets/Stone Ground.png', 'performanceTask Assets/Struct.png', 'performanceTask Assets/Wall.png', 'performanceTask Assets/Props.png', 'performanceTask Assets/Shadow Plant.png', 'performanceTask Assets/Shadow.png', 'performanceTask Assets/player.png'];

var atlasImage = new Image();

atlasImage.src = images[0];
atlasImage.onload = function() {
    let x = 0
    let y = 0
    for (let u = 0; u < 8; u++) {
        for (let i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            tiles["tiles" + (i+8*u)] = createImageBitmap(atlasImage, x, y, tileSize, tileSize)
            x += tileSize;
        }
        y += tileSize;
        x = 0;
    }
}

function grassScreen() {
    ctx.drawImage(tiles['tiles1'], 100, 100);
};

setInterval(grassScreen, 1000);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Work in Progress</title>
        <style>
            * {
                overflow: hidden;
            }
            html, body {
                margin: 0 !important;
                padding: 0 !important;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
        <script src="performanceTask.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You don't have a `canvas` element.

Comment: The canvas element is in the html.

Comment: Your `onload` is never called because the image is never loaded.

Comment: when I console.log the 'tiles' variable, it prints out 64 items correctly. Therefore the unload must have worked.

Comment: try this instead creating image like this var atlasImage = new Image(); try creating image like this document.createElement("img"); and then run your code

Answer (score 0):

It is giving a error like cannot read property of null that's because you have not created the canvas but still you are calling it with `getElementById` create a canvas element like this

```
canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
CTX = canvas.getContext('2d');
```

from this you will not get error

Comment: It still gives a type error.

Comment: @EmperorSai try to include your JS in the html file it could be possible that your file name is given wrong or something or it is in different folder,  just try to include it once in your html

Comment: it still an error. I believe the error has to do with the dictionary or the drawGrass function.

Comment: I thnk there is problem with images or the folder try removing the spaces from the original folder name and remove the space from dictionary values also then try it I tihnk it should work fine